# vuejs Dymanic Routes get param Id

Tags: api, vue.js, nuxt.js

user/index.vue

```
    <tbody>
      <tr
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.id"
      >
        <td v-if="false" v-text="item.id" />
        <td v-text="item.name" />
        <td v-text="item.phone" />
        <td> <a @click="go(item.id)">  Details  </a> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


.
.
.

methods: {
  go(idUser){
    this.$router.push({ 
      path: '/opr/:id',
      name: 'oprid',
      params:{ 
        id: idUser 
      } 
    })
  }
}
```

files:

```
-user
     -opr
         _id.vue
     index.vue
```

so, when I clicked in "details" the error 404 is showing.

you can see that is about a list(item), I created one function and I'm sending id,  I do this to make it more dynamic.

Comment: This is your Vue front end code, in order to know how to get data for id="22", you need your server code (is it node.js, dotnet core, something else?) and more detail about what kind of database you use (NoSql, Sql something else?). Take a look at this post [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, update router.

```
  {
    path: '/users/opr/:id',
    name: 'UserOpr',
    component: UserOpr
  },
```

You can use `id` in UserOpr as follow.

```
this.$route.params.id
```

Comment: I'm having some problem, I'll update mi question

Comment: it help me so much, but I'm having error 404

Comment: You can check router again. `path: '/opr/:id'`  This is what you defined now. Check the router if it is defined as `path: '/opr/:id'`

Comment: yes, it is....  { path: '/opr/:id',
          name: 'opr',
          component: opr }

Comment: Do you `opr` component?   `component: UserOpr` is just my imagination. You must give the exact component here.